# Sharepoint List Item field returning null using JSOM

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

Im fetching a field with multiple lines of text using JSOM and it returns null. All other fields return the correct value but attempting to get this results in null.

Is there a special way of getting values from fields which have multiple lines of text

Comment: Is Append Changes for this field enabled?

Comment: yes It was,i disabled it and reinserted the contents and its now working. Apparently it has something to do with the different versions of text when appending changes is enabled. I'll consider leveraging SPServices GetVersionCollection when dealing with fields that have version controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have Append Changes enabled you'll get back null as you've found.

Here's an example of using SPServices to get what you need:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2ab5b035-b96a-4aa2-8e1f-4b17bc1adcce/is-it-possible-to-get-the-historical-values-from-a-append-changes-to-existing-text-via-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious